# How to install the snapshot jar by Gradle?

Tags: spring-security

For [this project](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server), I want to install the jar files into my local repository. So far, I modified the `build.gradle` to this:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:spring-build-conventions:0.0.33.RELEASE'
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion"
        classpath 'io.spring.nohttp:nohttp-gradle:0.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal() // 使用本地仓库
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
}

plugins{
    id 'maven-publish'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.nohttp'
apply plugin: 'locks'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.convention.root'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'org.springframework.security.experimental'
description = 'Spring Authorization Server'

ext.snapshotBuild = version.contains("SNAPSHOT")

repositories {
    mavenLocal() // 使用本地仓库
    mavenCentral()
}

// 指定上传的路径
def localMavenRepo = 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath

// 上传Task，Gradle会生成并上传pom.xml文件。
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: localMavenRepo)
            //构造项目的Pom文件
            pom.project {
                name = project.name
                packaging = 'jar'
                description = 'description'
            }
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    // 配置发布的地址
    repositories{
        // 一. 这种方式是最简便的方式
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

dependencyManagementExport.projects = subprojects.findAll { !it.name.contains('-boot') }

subprojects {
    plugins.withType(JavaPlugin) {
        project.sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    }
}

nohttp {
    allowlistFile = project.file("etc/nohttp/allowlist.lines")
}
```

When running `gradle uploadArchives`, this is the error I received:

```
Execution failed for task ':spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:uploadArchives'.
Could not publish configuration 'archives'
Must specify a repository for deployment
```

Also, when running `artifactory publishing`, this is the error I received:

```
Execution failed for task ':artifactoryDeploy'.
java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 401 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
Artifactory configured to accept only encrypted passwords but received a clear text password, getting the encrypted password can be done via the WebUI. Status code: 401
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `install` task will deploy artifacts to Maven repositories, including local. See the [Maven Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) for details.

If you want to reference the snapshot jar for Spring Authorization Server then ensure you have the following in your gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.security.experimental:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}
```

For additional details, see the Spring Security reference for [Gradle setup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#getting-gradle).